# How to add Facebook login within a plugin in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, customization

I have created a plugin for voting a post. Now i want to add Facebook login within my plugin. i have searched so many and tried so many ways, but still its not resolved.

Please suggest me how to do it.

Comment: Check this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web

Comment: Still issue not resolved.